# Using iPad for an developing?

Tags: ipad, development

Can i use the iPad pro as my only machine for becominb a full stack web developer?
I currently use a pc and from what i know about web development for now can be done on iPad but can i do more complicated stuff like make web apps on iPad?

Answer (score 1):

You could, but it's not going to be very handy. The OS as well as the hardware aren't made for this kind of thing. If you want to become a full-stack developer, you might want to invest in proper tools :-).

Comment: what makes it less capable than a pc when it comes to web developing?